# How to configure maven resource plugin to complain when a property for resource filtering is not found?

Tags: maven, filter, resources

My question is simple: I want maven to give me some error messages when any property is not found  during resource filtering.
I didn't find any clue in the official maven docs.
So how could I do this?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot. See plugin parameters  : http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/copy-resources-mojo.html

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take a deep look at the [maven-enforcer-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/index.html) which can be used for such things:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>enforce-property</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>enforce</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <rules>
                <requireProperty>
                  <property>basedir</property>
                  <message>You must set a basedir property!</message>
                  <regex>.*\d.*</regex>
                  <regexMessage>The basedir property must contain at least one digit.</regexMessage>
                </requireProperty>
                <requireProperty>
                  <property>project.version</property>
                  <message>"Project version must be specified."</message>
                  <regex>.*(\d|-SNAPSHOT)$</regex>
                  <regexMessage>"Project version must end in a number or -SNAPSHOT."</regexMessage>
                </requireProperty>
              </rules>
              <fail>true</fail>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

Comment: Wow..does this mean all the properties I want it to be required must be configured in the enforce goal? It's too cumbersome.. I want a way which can report me any property missing automatically.